# how to code an if statement to do with 2 sets of arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone

I have an array of sprite positions and I have got another array of rects. If the array of sprite positions is in any of the array of rects i want to be able to move all those sprites in those rects in a certain way. I'm just not sure on how to code an if statement to do with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work:

```
for (NSObject *rectObject in rectArray) {
    for(NSObject *spriteObject in spriteArray){
        if (rectObject.origin.x<spriteObject.x>(rectObject.origin.x+rectObject.size.width)) {
            if (rectObject.origin.y<spriteObject.y>(rectObject.origin.y+rectObject.size.height)) {
                //do something;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error on the last brace saying selector element does not have a valid object type

Comment: what sort of arrays are you using? are they c style ones(array[]) or objective-c ones? also what are the object types? this code won't work as a drop in, but nested for loops would enable you to check each object.